# Handling Long Running Task in Cloud Function - Google Cloud Video Intelligence API

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, video-intelligence-api

We're currently using the `cloud intelligence api` for `tracking objects` in videos, but this may take > 10 minutes for large videos.

I'm curious if there is any functionality with Google Cloud products to publish to a pub/sub queue of sorts after a job is completed.

The only API appears to make us wait for `await operation.promise()`.

Amazon has a solution which allows the function to go to sleep, and you can just check if the job is completed later on.

Anyone know if this exists for Google?

```
  const [operation] = await video.annotateVideo(request);
  console.log('Waiting for operation to complete...');
  const [operationResult] = await operation.promise();
  // Gets shot changes
  let shotChanges = operationResult.annotationResults[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an [outputUri](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/reference/rest/v1/videos/annotate) which will write the results to your GCS bucket. If you do it this way, your method won't have to wait.

Then you can set up a trigger on the output GCS bucket that will process the result.